# I have a function script that I can't find it in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I am converting another script into Pine Script in `TradingView`, and I am currently couldn't find a function which I can "`Lookback or Refer`" as shown below:

```
REF（X，M）
Where, (X, is source), and (M, is length)
```

Is there anyone that can help to find, or help to advise?

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in pine-script is called **[History Referencing Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#History_Referencing_Operator_.28Square_Brackets_.5B.5D.29)**. With that, it is possible to refer to the historical values of any variable of a series type (values which the variable had on the previous bars). So, for example, `close[1]` returns yesterday's close price -which is also a series.

Comment: I have checked again my earlier script, and it is like below,

B=A1+A2+A3+A4-4*A5
TOWERC=EMA(B,2)
plot(TOWERC>=REF(TOWERC,1),TOWERC,REF(TOWERC,1),8,0),color=red, linewidth=1, style=linebr

Can I use close[1] to replace REF mentioned above?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access `TOWERC`’s previous value and not `close`’s. If that’s the case, you should use `TOWERC[1]`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me go back and try. Thanks a lot.